# Talend connector to Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, talend, google-cloud-dataproc

is it possible to connect Talend to Google Cloud Dataproc? And are there any connectors available for it?
On [1](https://www.talend.com/partners/technology/google-cloud-sql/) it says it does but can't find any documentation related to it.

If the above is true, I would also like to know if it's is possible to run a job on Spark/Hadoop in Dataproc using Talend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to connect Talend with [multiple Google Cloud products](https://www.talend.com/solutions/information-technology/google-cloud-integration/).

Specifically, Talend should support:

- Google BigQuery
- Google Cloud Dataproc
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Pub/Sub

I don't have a specific link on hand to walk through the install and configuration process; however, Talend should be able to provide such details if you [contact them](https://www.talend.com/contact/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @James